# Impossible to access an attribute Error

Tags: twig

I am starting with twig and I have a small issue. I can't figure out how to solve it. I want to check if the variable is not empty to set title page. I have tried "is not null" also.

```
{% if item is not empty %}
    {% block title "Item " ~ item.name %}
{% endif %}
```

When there is a Item object it works but when It's null doesn't work. Why it doesn't works? I get this error

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a NULL variable ("")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
{% if item is not defined %}
{% block title "Item " ~ item.name %}
{% endif %}
```

instead.

If needed, [look at the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/index.html)