# twig - impossible to access a key ("message") on a NULL variable

Tags: symfony, twig

Ok, First off, I know there have been similar questions asked about this subject

Such as:
[Impossible to access an attribute Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906823/impossible-to-access-an-attribute-error)

However, they don't exactly answer the question I have.
I am setting up a login system for an application I am writing and have been getting an error when trying to display the login authentication error messages.

I have the following code in my template:

```
{% if error %}
    {% block message %}{{ error.message }}{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

This is what I have in the controller that is calling the template:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
        $error = $request->attributes->get(
            SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
        );
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render(
            'SaveSecurityBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
            array(                    
                'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
                'error'   => $error,
            )
        );
}
```

This should be fairly simple, however I keep getting the following message when I try to load the login form:

```
Impossible to access a key ("message") on a NULL variable ("") in SaveSecurityBundle:Security:login.html.twig at line 5
```

I tried doing a dump of the `error` variable and got the following (I'm only including the lines up to the piece that I actually need, the actually dump is a couple thousand lines):

```
object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException)#49 (8) {
    ["token":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException":private]=>
object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken)#50 
["message":protected]=>
   string(15) "Bad credentials"
```

So the message is there, but for some reason when it is supposed to be passing the error object, it is passing a null reference.

I am at a complete loss as to how to fix this, my only solution so far has been to remove the `error` printout all together, which removes the ability to inform the user of why they have not been logged in.

Comment: $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR) return an object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're rendering the error message inside a Twig block and you can't put a block into an `if` block — it renders regardless of the condition.

One of the solutions would be to make the block wrap the `if` statement:

```
{% block message %}
    {% if error %}{{ error.message }}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, you were exactly right.  I didn't realize it would render the block regardless of the `if` statement.  Once I switched it around it works exactly like it's supposed to.